# how to save third party id facebook from app?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have a platform that each user is given an id. Let's call it myAppId. I want to my users to be able to connect to facebook. I have a facebook app set up where users can do that. However, when I return the list of friends who use the app, it only returns the facebook_id. I notice in the facebook graph API, there is a third_party_id property. How can I save my platform user ids to the third_party_id property for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `third_party_id` is a read-only ID that Facebook generates and permits you to share with third parties like ad networks as a unique identifier. Facebook considers the user's ID to be private information (they don't even give your app the real ID, but one that's specific to your application - and you're still not allowed to give that out to others).

Facebook provides no method for storing data on their systems about a user. Once a user connects to Facebook for your application, **you** are responsible for storing their Facebook ID in **your** database alongside their other data in your app.